# Java send txt file to Printer

Tags: java, printing, landscape

I have made a program that generates text files (.txt) and then displays them in a textArea. I want to take this one step farther and be able to print the text file. It feels like I have tried everything but always get the same result. The text file always varies in length and is normally more than one page long. Using the code below my text file prints but instead of printing multiple pages it prints each page on one/sixth of the a single sheet in landscape. I just need it to print normally. Vertically on multiple pages. I am running on a Linux environment and it is an Epson printer. Any suggestions or feedback would be greatly appreciated.

```
public static void tryDoc(){
    try{
        PrintRequestAttributeSet pras = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
        pras.add(OrientationRequested.PORTRAIT);
        DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.TEXT_PLAIN_UTF_8;
        PrintService printService[] = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(flavor, pras);
        PrintService defaultService = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
        PrintService service = ServiceUI.printDialog(null, 200, 200, printService, defaultService, flavor, pras);

        if(service != null){
            DocPrintJob job = service.createPrintJob();
            FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(FileName);
            DocAttributeSet das = new HashDocAttributeSet();
            Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(input,flavor,das);
            job.print(doc, pras);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Failed");
    }
}
```

[What printed page looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lvDP.jpg)

Comment: What happens when you try to print the same file outside of java?

Comment: Awesome question that I never thought of! It prints the same way as my error. Do you have any ideas why this would be? Am I generating the text file incorrectly? It looks normal when I view it.

Comment: The Java code just reads the system default printer, as far as I know. I haven't used those Java libraries, personally, so I'm not sure what the code would be to change that. I would think that the portrait orientation you specified would at least print vertically.

Comment: try setting `das.add(OrientationRequested.PORTRAIT);`